# How does the subq instruction and cf flag work together?

Tags: assembly, x86, carryflag, eflags

I've encountered two possibilities for how the carry flag can be set with:

```
0x00_00_00_00_00_00_00_00 - 0x80_00_00_00_00_00_00_00
```

(underscores to show bytes)

If I did this by subtraction, we would have to borrow from a bit we don't have, which should set the `CF` to `1`.

However, I was under the impression that ALUs do not subtract, but rather just add the two's complement. The two's complement of  `0x80_00_00_00_00_00_00_00` is `0x80_00_00_00_00_00_00_00`. So,
`0x00_00_00_00_00_00_00_00 - 0x80_00_00_00_00_00_00_00` does not carry any bits out of the 63 bit, which would set the `CF` to `0`.

Which of these situations is valid for 64 bit values in x86?

Does the ALU actually carry out a subtraction or does it convert to 2's complement and the converted values to do a subtraction?

Comment: Why haven't you tried it? x86 will subtract so it will set CF to 1. Some architectures do indeed use CF reversed for subtraction.

Comment: I'm not sure how to test this? How would I go about seeing the result? I'm in an introduction to systems class; everything is in C. I can view the disassembly, but I have no idea how to see the status registers? I could probably program something to try and infer what is happening, but I would love to know how to actually view the flags.

Comment: Use a debugger. `(gdb) p $eflags` gives `$1 = [ CF PF SF IF OF ]` Also, if you are coding in C, why do you care about flags? The compiler will take care of them...

Comment: I need to know how the flags work for my exams. Our lab is just C programs, but we're learning about x86 in class. Thanks, I check out the behavior. :)

Comment: You can also make an ALU that subtracts, and then implement addition on top of that. Which one of these the various x86's (there isn't just one implementation, while its a family with similar semantics the implementations can be (and are) very different) actually use in their ALU is impossible to find out by experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

See [Understanding Carry vs. Overflow conditions/flags](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt) to learn more about carry.

Yes of course any implementation of SUB still has to preserve the same architecturally-visible behaviour, including the flag results.

It doesn't matter how the ALU works internally, only what the results are, and zero minus non-zero produces a carry, so any x86 CPU will set CF in this situation.  Any CPU that doesn't is not an x86.

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to Intel's x86 manuals (and lots of other good links); I'm sure there's a section on flag-setting behaviour somewhere in the official manuals.

---

In practice, yes, presumably x86 CPUs use a normal [binary adder-subtractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder%E2%80%93subtractor), where sub / cmp is done by NOTing one input and feeding in a carry-in of `1` to the low bit.  (So there's only a single addition, so an input of `0` becomes `FFFFFFFF` with a carry-in of `1`, guaranteeing a carry-out from the ALU adder).

**Since x86 wanted the semantics of CF to be a borrow on subtraction, it has to invert the ALU adder's carry-out signal when doing subtraction, and x86 `sbb` has to invert it back.**

Some other ISAs, like ARM, have their carry flag indicate not-borrow, so ARM's `sbc` can feed the C flag directly into the ALU just like its `adc`.

See also *[Arithmetic identities and EFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62218921/arithmetic-identities-and-eflags/62219965#62219965)* re: emulating `sub` with `not` / `stc` / `adc`.  And I guess a `cmc` to complement CF afterwards.  I haven't checked if that would give correct output for OF signed-overflow.