# How is overflow detected when doing binary subtraction

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, twos-complement, integer-arithmetic

Assume we have 3 bits to play with. I am going to represent plus and minus 3 in 2's complement:

```
+3 = 0b011
-3 = 0b101
```

When doing **addition** you always have a dangling bit when an overflow happens like this `(-3) + (+3)`:

```
  1 0 1
+ 0 1 1
  -----
1 0 0 0
```

But what about **subtraction** `(-3) - (+3)`?

```
  1 0 1
- 0 1 1
  -----
  0 1 0
```

`0b010` is `2` which is not the correct result we expected being `-6`. There is an overflow
and the extra bit is not even generated so how will it get detected that there is an overflow?

I guess a correct way to tackle this is to sign extend the inputs first?

Comment: 3-bit 2's complement can only handle values in the -4 .. +3 range, so `-6` wraps to `+2`.  It doesn't make sense to "expect" a value that's not encodeable, but I assume that's just clumsy phrasing to talk about the correct mathematical result.  You can detect subtraction overflow when the inputs have opposite signs, and the output has a different sign from the first operand.

Comment: is it safe to say, when doing signed arithmetic we always have to sign extend the inputs to the result type first?

Comment: Storing a 3-bit number in an 8-bit byte can be done in a number of ways: ignore the upper 5 bits, sign extend 3 to 8, or shift the 3-bit number to the upper end so that the 5 bits that are going to be ignored are the lower 5 bits.  If you choose the first way, you will loose some features of the processor, such as overflow flags and sign flag, but there are other ways to obtain that information.

Comment: @ErikEidt Makes sense. I guess its not a rule then, it depends if the upper (widen) bits are going to be used or not.

Comment: @ErikEidt also what you mentioned can be applied to various sizes, i.e 8->32, 8->64, etc.

Comment: a better question would be, when do you sign extend inputs? is it simply when you expect the output will be wider than the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How signed overflow is detected in logic

```
(-3) - (+3) = (-3) + (-3) = (-3) + (~3) + 1
```

Using elementary school math and twos complement

```
    1
  101
+ 100
======
```

finish it

```
 1011
  101
+ 100
======
  010
```

SIGNED overflow happens when the carry in and carry out of the msbit are different.  Which we see here.  Another way to say that is, using the inverted operand B, if the msbits of the operands are the same and the result is not the same value then it is a signed overflow.

Note that the carry out of the msbit is a not borrow, so a 1 means there was no borrow and a 0 means there was.  Some processor architectures invert the carry out and call it a borrow bit, others do not.   Either solution works you just have to have your comparison logic match as well as subtract with borrow.

With grade school math we could just keep adding columns.  If we could simply add one more bit to a register we could get complete answers for addition and subtraction.  For multiplication we need twice as many bits. For 3 bit operands we need a 6 bit result to not overflow. To complement that you want a 6 bit numerator for a three bit divisor for division, ideally.   Not all instruction sets provide this. And yes for signed operations you need to sign extend and for unsigned you need to zero pad, thus the difference between a signed multiply and an unsigned multiply.   for 3 bit results (multiply) the signed/unsigned does not matter (do it on paper and pencil like grade school and this should be obvious).  Likewise with 3 bit addition or subtraction there is no need to know unsigned vs signed.

With addition and subtraction though the normal solution is add with carry and subtract with borrow. -3 - +3 gives -6 which we cannot represent with 3 bits, we need 4 but if we assume 3 bit registers then the only thing we can do is 6.  Which means we are really trying to do 111101 - 000011.

```
     1011
   111101
  +111100
    ======
      010
```

and if we visually do this and cut it in half

```
     1   011
   111   101
  +111   100
  ============
         010
```

we can complete the subtraction using a second instruction (subtract with borrow)

```
  1111 
   111 
  +111 
  =====
   111
```

111010 is -6, no overflow.  The key is to get the carry out of the lower half into the carry in of the upper half.

If the architecture inverts the carry bit on the way out of the subtract then it needs to invert the borrow bit on the way into a subtract with borrow, otherwise if it does not invert it out of sub then don't invert it into sbb.  Add and adc (add with carry) work the same way, just nothing is inverted, the carry bit comes into adc as the carry in of the msbit.

Multiply is not as simple it is not a single bit thing you need a whole registers worth of bits, so some architectures will give you that 3 bits times 3 bits equals 6 bits signed and unsigned multiply instructions.  But for addition and subtraction there is no real need, use the carry bit and an additional instruction with the memory/registers that contain the rest of the bits.  You can add/subtract as wide as you have memory/registers,  1000 bit plus 1000 bit is easy it is just one add and a bunch of adcs in a row.

Comment: Thanks for the information, regarding `when do we sign extend the input?`, is it sufficient to say we do so when we expect the output is bigger than the inputs?

Comment: no i mean, when you multiply and the result is wider than the input, or when you add and the result becomes bigger than the original data types, i'm trying to confirm these are the situations where you sign extend the inputs.

Comment: true but even doing add/subtraction, you still need to sign extend if the output grows bigger than the input data types, you can either sign extend the inputs, or just sign extend the output. i.e adding two 8 bit chars which could overflow into a 16 bit halfword.

Comment: true that was the original question which sort of got derailed into sign extension and all, but thanks for answering my original problem. Regarding `addition with carry` I guess its more specific to x64, other architecture may allow an overflow into the sign bit (as well as setting overflow flags).

Comment: answer re-written now that I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

An overflow flag can be created by (carry into the MSB) XOR (carry out of the MSB).

Comment: Does that work for a [binary subtractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractor) as well as an adder?   Or only after you implement a binary subtractor by transforming one input and feeding it to a chain of full adders?  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder%E2%80%93subtractor)