# How the carry flag is influenced by subtraction

Tags: assembly, x86, integer-arithmetic, carryflag

I'm learning a computer architecture course.

My teacher told me that signed integers are stored in two's complement, and that when doing subtraction, for example, x - y, the complement of y is added to x.

This course also teaches some assembly language. I learned that the carry flag is set after an operation if the operation generates a carry or a borrow out of the most significant
bit of the result.

Given the above knowledge, I am confused by the result of the following examples:

```
example1:
; eax = C2h, ecx = 22h
sub eax, ecx 
; after this, cf = 0

example2:
; eax = 22h, ecx = C2h
sub eax, ecx
; after this, cf = 1
```

The first example is to calculate

```
C2 - 22 =
C2 + (FFFFFFDE) =
C0 + overflowed 2^32 carried out of the most significant bit
```

, for which I think that cf should be set

And the second example is to calculate

```
22 - C2 =
22 + FFFFFF3E =
FFFFFF60 with no overflow, so no carry out of the most significant bit
```

, for which I think that cf should not be set

Why the actual result turned out to be the very contrary? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: On x86, CF is a "borrow" output from subtraction. (Fun fact: opposite of ARM where it's a !borrow flag).  It matters how you get there, and it's *not* equivalent to turning it into addition like `neg` / `add`.  See [Arithmetic identities and EFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219965)

Comment: To add to what Peter said, you can always use a `cmc` instruction to flip the carry flag.

Comment: @PeterCordes -are there any currently made processors that use subtract logic instead of complement and add logic?

Comment: @rcgldr: No idea.  Probably not, though.